# php saving variables from post and update the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've got a form that sends variable(id) by a button on a php files that should take that ID, 
connect to my mysql database, and take the data "partecipanti" based on my "id", increment by 1 the "partecipanti"'s number and update the database.
but it doesn't work.
why?
this is my eventi.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.1.js.js"></script> <!--PER EVENTI-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stile.css"> <!--PER EVENTI-->
    <script src="JS/func.js"></script> <!--PER EVENTI-->
    <?php include ("PHP/phpfiles.php");?> <!--PER EVENTI-->
    <script src="JS/snap.js"></script> <!--TBAR-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/demo.css"><!--TBAR-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/snap.css"><!--TBAR-->
    <title>Eventi</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="snap-drawers">
            <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left">
                <div>

                    <h5>Menu</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="eventi.php">Eventi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="FACEBOOK_ALBUM/albums.php">Album foto eventi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="dragElement.html">Contatti</a></li>
                        <li><a href="rightDisabled.html">Credits</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content" class="snap-content">
            <div id="toolbar">
                <a href="#" id="open-left"></a>
                <h1>BPARTY</h1>
            </div>
            <br> <br>
            <?
$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "bestparty";
$DBpass = "";
$DBName = "my_bestparty";

/* specifichiamo il nome della nostra tabella */
$table = "Dati";

/* Connettiamoci al database */
mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass) or die("Impossibile collegarsi al server");
@mysql_select_db("$DBName") or die("Impossibile connettersi al database $DBName");

/* impostiamo la query ORDINANDO IN ORDINE DECRESCENTE PER ID */

$numerofesta = $_GET['idfesta'];



$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID = $numerofesta";
$result = mysql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
/*assegnamo e stampiamo le variabili*/


      $festa = mysql_result($result,$i,"festa");
      $data = mysql_result($result,$i,"data");
      $luogo = mysql_result($result,$i,"luogo");
      $prezzo = mysql_result($result,$i,"prezzo");
      $organizzatore = mysql_result($result,$i,"organizzatore");  
      $facebook = mysql_result($result,$i,"linkevento");
      $listapr = mysql_result($result,$i,"listapr");
      $dettagli = mysql_result($result,$i,"Dettagli");
      $nonpartecipanti = mysql_result($result,$i,"nonpartecipanti");
      $partecipanti = mysql_result($result,$i,"partecipanti");
      $imageUrl = "../fotofeste/$organizzatore.png";
      if (!$organizzatore){
          $organizzatore = "nophoto";
      }
      echo"<img src='../fotofeste/$organizzatore.png?12345689' class=\"imamgineeventocompleta\"/>";
      if (!$facebook) {
          $facebook = "www.bparty.org";
      }
   ?>

        <div id="contenitore">






   <div class="testievento"> <font color="#000000"><? echo"$festa" ?></font>
   <div style="margin-top:13px;">
   <table id="tabellaelenchi">
   <tr>
  <td> <font color="#DC3F42"><? echo"$prezzo"; ?></font> </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <font color="#534F4F"><? echo"$luogo" ?></font> </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <font color="#534F4F"><? echo"$data" ?></font> </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <font color="#4B5998"><? echo"<a href='http://$facebook' class=\"testofacebook\">LINK EVENTO SU FACEBOOK</a>" ?></font> </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <font color="#534F4F"><? echo"$dettagli" ?></font> <br> <br> <br> </td> 
   </tr>
   </table>

    <div id="parteciperai">
    <form action="PHP/partecipero.php">
    <button name="numerofesta" value="<? echo"$numerofesta" ?>" type="submit">PARTECIPERO</button>
    </form>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"><a href="tel:+393334784355"><font size="+1">Info e Prevendite</font></a></div>



</div>
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var snapper = new Snap({
                element: document.getElementById('content')
            });

        </script>




    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the php file

```
 <? 
                                    $id = $_POST['numerofesta'];



                                    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","bestparty","");
                                    $table = "Dati";


                            if ($db == FALSE)
                            die ("Errore nella connessione. Verificare i parametri nel file config.inc.php");

                            mysql_select_db("my_bestparty", $db)
                            or die ("Errore nella selezione del database. Verificare i parametri nel file config.inc.php");

                            $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
/*assegnamo e stampiamo le variabili*/



      $partecipanti = mysql_result($result,$i,"partecipanti");
        $partecipantinew = $partecipanti + 1;
                             $query="UPDATE `Dati` SET `partecipanti`='$partecipantinew' WHERE `ID`=$idfesta "; 

                              echo"$id";
                           ?>
```

Comment: First a side note: Stop using the deprecated mysql_* php extension and start using PDO. You're wide open to SQL Injections. Second, what do you get? Do you get an error message or anything?

Comment: your form lacks `method` attribute. Since you want to get submitted info using `$_POST`, you should add `method="post"` to `<form>`

Comment: When did this wall of code stop working? Or did you expect it to work first time? Please provide a minimum of code which identifies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

like @lolbas says, change:

```
<form action="PHP/partecipero.php">
```

to

```
<form action="PHP/partecipero.php" method="POST">
```